# How to autofill employee ctc when employee name is selected in openerp7?

Tags: odoo

I am trying to get a CTC using onchange function of an employee on depending on the selected user from hr.employee and has followed the above methods but the results are not reflecting can some one help me with this

```python
def get_emp_ctc(self, cr, uid, ids, user_id, context=None):
    v={}
    if user_id:
        employee = self.pool.get('hr.employee').browse(cr, uid, user_id, context=context)
    if employee.nf_ctc.id:
        v['emp_ctc'] = employee.nf_ctc and employee.nf_ctc.id or False
    return {'value': v}
```

Comment: Did you declare that function in the view to work as an onchange for the user_id field?

Comment: yes i have declared in view.xml

Comment: And did you try to log the employee to see if you have a record?

Comment: sorry dany i din't get your question.. can u ask me in detail??

Comment: add this below the openerp imports

import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

add under employee variable:
_logger.info('employee %s', employee)

tell me the output of that

Comment: iam geeting a error like below
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: parse the error, wheres the syntax erorr?